# index.html is not detecting tailwind css classes

Tags: html, css, frontend, tailwind-css

I followed the getting started guide [here](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/installation).

steps:

1.
`npm install -D tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest`

2.
`npx tailwindcss init`

3. create the following config files

postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  }
}
```

tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  purge: [
    './src/**/*.html',
    './src/**/*.js',],
  darkMode: false,
  content: [],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

4. create styles.css
   src/styles.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

5. build css file
   `npx tailwindcss -o public/tailwind.css`
6. make index.html file in the same folder as tailwind.css, and added one tailwind class to change text color

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="tailwind.css">
</head>
<body class="text-yellow-600"><h1>Hello World</h1></body>
</html>
```

############################

Here is my ending file structure (excluding the node_modules folder)

```
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── postcss.config.js
├── public
│   ├── index.html
│   └── tailwind.css
├── src
│   └── styles.css
└── tailwind.config.js
```

When I open my index.html file I expect hello world to have yellow text, but it appears to not be recognizing the tailwind css classes.

I tried renaming styles.css to tailwind.css. I tried a bunch of different styles for the h1 tag and the body tag but none of the tailwind classes are being recognized.

I was expecting those classes to start being styled

I think there is an issue with the tailwind imports base, components, and utilities give vscode is giving me yellow squiggly lines:

In my public/tailwind.css folder I don't see all of the classes that are in the documentation. I am missing something here in the setup and I can't figure out what it is, any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your paths are incorrect.

Index.html and tailwind.css are in the public directory. So tailwind.config will look like this

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  purge: [
    './public/**/*.html',
    './public/**/*.js',],
  darkMode: false,
  content: [],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

and in index.html try adding a forward slash to the tailwind.css file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/tailwind.css">
```

Comment: Thanks, the issue was adding './' to my link...

Comment: If my answer helped please mark it as solved.